# disable firewalld/iptables in centos7 minimal version

Tags: docker, centos7

I have a centos:7 minimal image on my docker and I want to stop iptables/firewalld but the official centos:7 image that I have downloaded from docker repository does not support systemctl/service .
guide me to stop iptables/firewalld on this minimal centos:7

I tried
setenforce 0
& disabled selinux

Answer (score 3):

The official `centos:7` minimal image has no `firewalld` installed, and `iptables` is not running by default.

```
$ docker run -it centos:7 bash
[root@f4d4d29f4ca4 /]# find / -name 'fire*'
[root@f4d4d29f4ca4 /]# find / -name 'iptables*'
/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service
/usr/sbin/iptables
/usr/sbin/iptables-save
/usr/sbin/iptables-restore
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/iptables
/usr/libexec/iptables
/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init
/usr/bin/iptables-xml
[root@f4d4d29f4ca4 /]# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.1  11748  2916 ?        Ss   12:13   0:00 bash
root        40  0.0  0.1  19752  2244 ?        R+   12:16   0:00 ps aux
```

`selinux` is not installed either:

```
[root@f4d4d29f4ca4 /]# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
cat: /etc/sysconfig/selinux: No such file or directory
```